# How would you explain Characteristic Function in layman's terms?

Tags: probability, random-variable, characteristic-function

- What is a Characteristic Function?
- Why is it needed?

Can you explain it in layman's terms and along with a simple & easy example?

---

Please, limit using formal math notations as far as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Characteristic Function is the Fourier transform of a distribution, I would appeal to interpretations of this. For instance:

> What does the Fourier Transform do? Given a smoothie, it finds the recipe.
>
> How? Run the smoothie through filters to extract each ingredient.
>
> Why? Recipes are easier to analyze, compare, and modify than the smoothie itself.
>
> How do we get the smoothie back? Blend the ingredients.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)

https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-interactive-guide-to-the-fourier-transform/

Comment: Can I have an example, plz?